# Initialize array after declaring in C

Tags: c, macros

I am trying to do the following but am getting the following error:

> "error: expected expression before `{` token

**Test_Stubs.h**

```
#define SIGNATURE 0x78,0x9c
```

**Test.c**

```
#include "Test_Stubs.h"

static unsigned myArray[100];

static void
setup(void)
{
    myArray = {SIGNATURE};
}
```

**EDIT**

Follow on question:

Is there a way to assign the individual values in the `#define` to specific indexes of myArray? For instance...

```
#include "Test_Stubs.h"

static unsigned myArray[100];

static void
setup(void)
{
    myArray[0] = SIGNATURE[0]; //0x78
    myArray[1] = SIGNATURE[1]; //0x9c
}
```

Clearly the above code will not code as SIGNATURE is neither an array or pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the `C` syntax rules, you can only initialize an array using a brace enclosed initializer list at the time of definition.

Afterwards, you have to initialize element by element, using a loop, or, if you need to initialize all the elements to the same value, you can consider using [`memset()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset).

---

EDIT:

No, as I mentioned in my comments, as per your code snippet, `SIGNATURE` is neither an array name, nor represent any array type, so you cannot use indexing on that.

However, using [compound literal](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) (on and above `C99`), if you change your `#define`, then, somehow, you can make this work. See the below code for example,

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIGNATURE ((unsigned [100]){0x78,0x9c})

static unsigned myArray[100];

int main (void)
{
    myArray[0] = SIGNATURE[0]; //0x78
    myArray[1] = SIGNATURE[1]; //0x9c

    return 0;
}
```

See a <kbd>[LIVE VERSION](http://ideone.com/QAWz4o)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. I had a quick follow on question if you don't mind addressing. See edit.

Comment: @ILostMySpoon `SIGNATURE` it not an array type variable, even not an array type after preprocessing stage. So, you cannot use indexing on it.

Comment: What would be the best workaround to achieve what I am trying to do?